# Conditional Statement in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In a journey, I'd like to check if a customer opened the email AND completed his profile in the Preference Center to send him to different paths. For the opening email I'd use the Engagement Split Activity; to check the completed profile a Decision Split Activity. However, how can I create the AND / OR statements in JB? Is there a way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create an automation with a query that JOINs the _open dataview with the data extension that is storing the data from the profile center.  Details on the _open data view: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5

2.) Create a data extension to capture the output from the query (select statement), include the subscriber id to link to the journey entrant.

3.) Create a custom attribute in Contact Builder > Data Designer and attached the DE from #2

4.) In your decision split find the custom attribute under Contact data and select the appropriate fields needed for your different paths.